# How to mock Interface in JUnit instead of its implementation class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a problem to write JUnit Service Test shown below.

I only access **UserService** (Interface) and **UserServiceImpl** cannot be accessed from outside as it is private. This is my case.

I have a problem to call `saveUser` method.

Here is the structure

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       └── com
│           ├── company
│               ├── service
│                    ├── UserService.java
│                    ├── impl
│                         ├── UserServiceImpl.java (package-private)
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── company
                ├── UserServiceTest.java
```

Here is the UserService shown below

```
public interface UserService {
    UserDTO saveUser(SignUpRequest signUpRequest);
}
```

Here is the save Method defined in UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

       private final UserRepository userRepository;

       @Transactional
       public UserDTO saveUser(SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
       ...
       return UserDTO.builder()
                    .username(signUpRequest.getUsername())
                    .firstName(signUpRequest.getFirstName())
       }
}
```

Here is the UserServiceTest shown below

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@Test
void shouldCreateUser() {
   User user = new User();
   ...
   when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);

   UserDTO savedUserDTO = userService.saveUser(signUpRequest);  // Here is the issue

   
}
```

I get this issue shown below

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'userService'! Cause: the type 'UserService' is an interface.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
Examples of correct usage of @InjectMocks:
   @InjectMocks Service service = new Service();
   @InjectMocks Service service;
   //and... don't forget about some @Mocks for injection :)
```

When I changed userService as shown below, I get this issue.

```
@Mock
private UserService userService;

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.backend.user.service.dto.UserDTO.getUsername()" because "savedUserDTO" is null
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: In your case `@InjectMocks` annotation doesn't know what implementation of `UserService` to inject.  See same issue here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/07/mockito-cannot-instantiate-injectmocks-field-the-type-is-an-interface.html

Comment: where is `UserServiceImpl` and how is it private?

Comment: @rostIvan I couldn't access UserServiceImpl as it is private as you can see. I couldn't do `private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository)`. How can I do that?

Comment: As far I see the class `UserServiceImpl` is package-private

Comment: @rostIvan You're right. It is package-private.

Comment: @rostIvan Can you revise your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an interface in `Java`. While using `@InjectMock` you tell **Mockito** to instantiate your object and inject your dependency, here `UserRepository`.

The first approach is to use a concrete implementation of your interface. Check this [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/07/mockito-cannot-instantiate-injectmocks-field-the-type-is-an-interface.html) for more details.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Test
    void shouldCreateUser() {
   
    }
}
```

Also the class under test is **UserService** so you can't the annotation `Mock` on it.

Answer (score 2):

The Mockito framework needs to know what concrete class to instantiate.
Since the class `UserServiceImpl` is package-private you can access it when your test case package is the same.

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       └── com
│           ├── company
│               ├── service
│                    ├── UserService.java
│                    ├── impl
│                         ├── UserServiceImpl.java (package-private)
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── company
                ├── service
                     ├── impl
                          ├── UserServiceTest.java
```

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository);

    @Test
    void shouldCreateUser() {
        // ... 
    }

}
```

Comment: I added a structure of package in the post.